# Version comment when adding a document version

Tags: versioning, version-history, version-comments

I would like to add a version comment in version history.

I have a file in a library with all it properties entered.
I then draw a new version of the file over the library windows and add a new version.
Great method, but it doesn't seem to have any connection to checkout, check in or the check in version comment.

Check out is set to required.
We are adding tif or pdf files of drawigns.  We will not be editing the files with Sharepoint or Office.

Seems like I have to checkout and check in just to add a comment.  I can edit any other property any time and I can add a new version any time.

Is there anyway to prompt the users with some sort of data entry form when a version is added?
Ideally the version comment form.

Answer (score 0):

A correction to the process above.
If I have checkout enabled I can not drag and drop a new version of the file into the library.
I don't know why I wasn't seeing this initially.  Maybe closing the web browser and refreshing the web page had something to do with it.

This is an acceptable method for us to force a version comment form to open.  It woul d be nice if it just happened rather then require the extra mouse clicks but understandable because of the possible online edits.